# How to disable all automatic pace preloader event

Tags: javascript, plugins

I'm trying to use [Pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/) preloader plugin. I want to disable all automatic preloader and i want to happen on particular event. I checked the document and i given code like below

```
Pace.options = {
     ajax: false,
        document: false, 
      eventLag: false, 
      elements:false
}
```

If i give this before `pace.js` inclusion then i might get a error saying it is undefined. But i cannot include it after the inclusion of the script also, as it is called automatically and immediately. So i tried the following `window` option

```
    window.paceOptions = {
  ajax: false,
    document: false, 
  eventLag: false, 
  elements:false
}
```

and tried another code using HTML data option

```
<script data-pace-options='{ "document":false,"eventLag:":false,"elements":false,"ajax": false }' src="../pace.js"></script>
```

But none worked. I'm seeing the preloader when the page is loaded. I don't want to get it.

How to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it. `startOnPageLoad` does the trick

```
paceOptions = {
               startOnPageLoad:false
       }
```